# Fix the plot size after displaying a matrix with spy

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-3.4

I have a matplotlib figure that  am using embedded into a pyQT GUI, therefore I need to recycle the figure to display several resuls.

When I display a matrix using the `spy` function, I get what I spect:
[image]

However when I clear the figure and plot a series I get this:
[image]
Instead of this:
[image]
Which I get if I plot the series without displaying a matrix before.

So a script to reproduce the issue is:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

mat = numpy.random.randn(20, 20)

# display the matrix
ax.spy(mat, markersize=5)


x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2 + x - 5

ax.clear()
ax.plot(x, y)
```

I have also tried

```
ax.relim()      # make sure all the data fits
ax.autoscale()  # auto-scale
```

But it doesn't do anything noticeable.

Comment: You could use `fig.clear()` and then re-add a new subplot `fig.add_subplot(111)`

Answer (score 0):

[`plt.spy`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.spy) will automatically set the aspect ratio of the axes to `'equal'` in order to ensure that the sparsity plot for a square matrix looks square. If the x-axis scale of your series is much larger than that of the y-axis, an equal aspect ratio will result in a very long and thin line plot.

To switch back to the 'default' mode where the aspect ratio is determined automatically you can call [`ax.set_aspect('auto')`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect):

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure, show
import numpy

fig = figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

mat = numpy.random.randn(20, 20)

# display the matrix
ax.spy(mat, markersize=5)

x = numpy.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2 + x - 5

ax.clear()
ax.set_aspect('auto')
ax.plot(x, y)
```

[image]